# Eliminar columnas

Tags: r, dplyr

Tengo el siguiente problema en `Rstudio`. Estoy usando `write.table` para guardar mi archivo en formato .SIF, y lo que sucede es que quiero eliminar 2 columnas de las 5 que tengo, Lo estoy intentando hacer con el siguiente código:

```
write.table(temp, 
          file = paste("./", nombre.carpeta, "/", gen, ".SIF", sep=""), 
          quote = FALSE, row.names = F) %>% temp %>% 
select(temp, -c(abs.value, signo))
```

... y me marca error, entonces, pido por favor me puedan ayudar con esto, en este caso quiero eliminar las columnas abs.value y signo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes algunos errores de concepto:

1. Cuando usas el "pipe", justamente evitas el tener que ir pasando el resultado de cada "verbo" al siguiente, en tu caso `temp` lo estas copiando en cada función.
2. El orden no es el adecuado: primero partimos de `temp` luego eliminamos columnas y por último salvamos el archivo

Tu lote de comandos debería ser algo así:

```
temp %>% 
  select(-c(abs.value, signo)) %>% 
  write.table(file = paste("./", nombre.carpeta, "/", gen, ".SIF", sep=""), 
              quote = FALSE, row.names = F)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me corrió bien, estoy aprendiendo a entender las sintaxis de manera correcta, estaría muy agradecido si me podría sugerir literatura para ello... Atte Rick

Comment: Yo comenzaría con este texto: https://es.r4ds.hadley.nz/

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, lo revisaré completo y nuevamente gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @Ricky No te olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si todas tus dudas quedaron solucionadas.